# Does AppStore download URL change after I change the app name?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I need to change my iOS app name (in iTunesConnect) in the new version. One thing I am not sure is whether the download link changes after the new-name version is online, since the name is included in the iTunes download URL.

I need to be sure because I include the URL in my code to direct potential users to the download link. If the link does change, how can I get the new link? or is the link fixed after submitting the initial version?

Comment: Update for anyone searching for this: the name part of URL does change after updating the name, but that doesn't matter, as the old URL (with the old name) is still working.

Answer (score 0):

When you update the name, does it not show you a new link in the iTunesConnect?

Best to contact Apple on this one buddy.

1-800-MY-APPLE (1-800-692-7753)